# Prove that exists matrices $B,C \in \mathcal{M}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ such that: $A=B^2+C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that exists matrices $B,C \in \mathcal{M}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ such that:
$$A=B^2+C^2$$

Comment: Sorry, no. It's a conjecture, but can you tell me why, that matrix is not satisfying.

Comment: @RoadHuman if its a conjecture the least you can do is mention that in the OP and try to come up with a few examples in support of your conjecture :)

Comment: my exercise is : $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$. I think it's a theorem.

Comment: For a complete answer see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20874/warings-problem-for-matrices).

Answer (score 10):

@ Road Human , your question is very poorly drafted. The example due to Alex is not a counter-example.

If $K $ is a field, then any $n\times n$ matrix (where $n\geq 2$) can be expressed as a sum of $3$ squares. cf.

Matrices as sums of squares. Linear and Multilinear Algbra 5 (1977), 33-44.

Moreover,the only matrices that cannot be expressed as sum of $2$ squares are the $cI_n$ where $n$ is odd and $c\in K$ cannot be expressed as sum of $2$ squares. cf.

Matrices as sums of squares ; a conjecture of Griffin and Krusemeyer. Linear and Multilinear Algbra 17 (1985), 289-294.

EDIT 1. I fixed 2 mistakes reported by Marc, user1551 and Dietrich.

EDIT 2. Answer to Road Human ($n=4$). We assume that a decomposition is known for any matrix with dimension $2,3$. We assume that $A$ is in its real Jordan form. Only $3$ cases cannot be reduced to block matrices of dimension $2,3$ or a block $\geq 0$ of dimension $1$:

Case 1: $A=aI_4+N$ where $N^4=0$. Let $B=diag(U,U)$ where $U=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and let $u$ s.t. $a+u^2>0$. Then $A-(uB)^2=(a+u^2)I_4+N=(a+u^2)(I_4+M)$ where $M^4=0$. Finally $A=(uB)^2+C^2$ where $C=\sqrt{a+u^2}(I+1/2M-1/8M^2+\cdots)$ (my Taylor is rich).

Case 2. $A=\begin{pmatrix}U&I_2\\0&U\end{pmatrix}$ where $U=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}=\rho R(\theta)$ where $\rho >0$ and $R$ is a rotation. In fact $A$ is a square because it has no $\leq 0$ eigenvalues. More precisely $A=B^2$ where $B=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{\rho}R(\theta/2)&\dfrac{R(-\theta/2)}{2 \sqrt{\rho}}\\0&\sqrt{\rho}R(\theta/2)\end{pmatrix}$.

Case 3. $A=diag(aI_3+N,b)$ where $N^3=0$ and $b<0$.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20874/warings-problem-for-matrices.

Comment: Nice answer; however I'm pretty sure the $1\times 1$ real matrix with entry $-1$ cannot be written as a sum of three squares of real matrices.

Comment: When $\mathbb K=\mathbb R,\, n=2$ and $c=-1$, the matrix $cI_n=-I_2$ is a sum of squares of two real matrices. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @user1551: The only matrices in $M_n(K)$ not being a sum of two squares are the matrices $-pI_n$ for $n$ **odd**, and $p$ not the sum of two squares in $\mathbb{R}$. So yes, for $n=2$ all matrices are the sum of two squares.

Comment: Existence a simple solution for $n=4$?

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been discussed in several papers, e.g., see [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0447170). For the field of real numbers, $-I_n$ is not the sum of two squares in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ for $n$ odd. So the answer is *positive* if $n$ is even, and *negative* if $n$ is odd. The question also has been asked on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20874/warings-problem-for-matrices).

A more interesting case is perhaps what happens for integral matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$. [Leonid Vaserstein](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081088608817738?journalCode=glma20#.VK-p212wIWM) proved that for $n\ge 2$ every integral matrix is the sum of *three* squares.